# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type' в pyTelegramBot

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю Telegram бот на python с помощью библиотеки pyTelegramBotApi. Суть в том, что у меня есть вот такой код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from clickupython import client

token = 'token' #здесь мой токен
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
c = client.ClickUpClient("token") #здесь мой токен


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def button_message(message):
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1=types.KeyboardButton("Просмотреть задачи")
    item2=types.KeyboardButton("Создать задачу")
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Здравствуйте,{0.first_name} {0.last_name}, выберите действие:',reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def message_reply(message):
    if message.text=="Просмотреть задачи":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ID | Имя | Описание | Создатель | Ссылка на задачу")
        tasks = c.get_tasks("210333950")
        for task in tasks:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, task.id, " | ", task.name," | ", task.description, " | ", task.creator.username, " | ", task.url)

    elif message.text=="Создать задачу":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я работаю над этим")

bot.infinity_polling()
```

А ошибка у меня вот такая

```
2022-09-06 17:51:57,345 (__init__.py:878 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'"
2022-09-06 17:51:57,346 (__init__.py:880 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 874, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 946, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1021, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 25, in message_reply
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, task.id, " | ", task.name," | ", task.description, " | ", task.creator.username, " | ", task.url)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1451, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 271, in send_message
    payload['entities'] = json.dumps(types.MessageEntity.to_list_of_dicts(entities))
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 1291, in to_list_of_dicts
    res.append(MessageEntity.to_dict(e))
  File "C:\Users\Simon\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 1315, in to_dict
    return {"type": self.type,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У

```
send_message
```

Второй параметр - текст сообщения.

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, task.id, " | ", task.name," | ", task.description, " | ", task.creator.username, " | ", task.url)
```

У меня первый параметр - message.chat.id, второй - task.id, третий - " | ", четвертый - task.name и тд

Строка не будет складываться как в print. Надо использовать любой удобный вариант формирования строки

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{task.id} | {task.name} | {task.description} | {task.creator.username} | {task.url}")
```